# Implications between notions of universal covering in categorical Galois theory

Tags: category-theory, covering-spaces

A while ago I made a generally wrong calculation which led me to [ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2078998/223002) whether the endomorphisms of a universal cover of a space are necessarily automorphisms.

Going through some papers of Janelidze, remark 5.2 of the paper *Categorical Galois theory - revision and some recent developments* touches related matters and even affirms my suspicion. However, I am struggling with filling in the details. For the sake of completeness we give some definitions. Throughout, we fix an admissible adjunction $\Pi_0\dashv H$ and suppose the domain of $\Pi_0$ has pullbacks.

**Definitions.**

- An object is Galois closed if its coverings are trivial.
- A covering $\alpha:A\to B$ is *connected* if $\Pi_0\alpha$ is an isomorphism.

We shall say an arrow *splits* a covering morphism if pulling back along the arrow trivializes the covering morphism.

**Definitions.** An effective descent covering morphism $p:E\to B$ is said to be:

- *Maximal* if $E$ is Galois closed.
- *Weakly universal* if it splits all coverings of $B$.
- *Projective* if it factors through any other effective descent morphism to $B$.
- *Universal* if it's weakly universal, projective, and every endomorphism is an automorphism.

**Remark 5.2.**

1. Maximal $\implies $ weakly universal. The converse is true if covering morphisms are closed under composition.
2. If a weakly universal covering exists, projective $\implies$ weakly universal.
3. If a weakly universal covering exists, connected projective $\implies $ universal.

I managed to prove the first implication of (1) and also (2) in a fairly straightforward manner. However I am lost with the converse of (1) and also with (3). I feel I must be missing simple diagrams. For (3) I suspect the orthogonality of arrows inverted by $\Pi_0$ and trivial coverings should be used, but I don't see how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the converse of (1) : let $q:E'\to E$ be a covering, and assume that $pq:E'\to B$ is a covering. Since $p$ is weakly universal, it splits itself and $pq$. So in the diagram
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}E'@>>> E\times_B E' @>>> E'\\
@V{q}VV (1) @V{\pi_2^*(q)}VV (2) @VV{q}V \\ 
E@>{\delta}>> E\times_BE @>{\pi_2}>> E\\
& @V{\pi_1}VV (3) @VV{p}V\\
& & E@>>{p}>B\end{CD}$$
where the squares $(2)$ and $(3)$ are pullbacks, $\pi_1$ and $\pi_1\circ \pi_2^*(q)$ are trivial, and thus $\pi_2^*(q)$ is trivial (as one can see by applying the classical pullback lemma to the naturality squares). Now if the top arrow of $(1)$ is chosen in such a way that the top composition is the identity on $E'$, then the rectangle $(1)+(2)$ is a pullback, and thus so is the square $(1)$. Since trivial extension are stable under pullbacks, $q$ is trivial.

For (3), if $f:E\to E$ be such that $pf=p$. Since $p$ is weakly universal by (2), the same argument shows that $\pi_2^{*}(f)$ is trivial in the sense that
$$\begin{CD}E\times_B E @>{\eta_{E\times_B E}}>> H\Pi_0(E\times_B E) \\ @V{\pi_2^{*}(f)}VV @VV{H\Pi_0(\pi_2^{*}(f))}V \\
E\times_BE @>{\eta_{E\times_B E}}>> H\Pi_0(E\times_B E) \end{CD}$$
is a pullback. Since moreover $\pi_2$ is a trivial covering (because $p$ splits itself), the pullback of the square $(2)$ (with $f$ instead of $q$) is preserved, and thus in
$$\begin{CD} E@>>> E\times_B E @>>> E @>{\eta_{E}}>> H\Pi_0(E)\\ @V{f}VV (1) @V{\pi_2^*(f)}VV (2) @VV{f}V (4) @VV{H\Pi_0(f)}V\\ E @>>{\delta}> 
 E\times_BE @>{\pi_2}>> E @>>> H\Pi_0(E)\\
\end{CD}$$
the rectangle $(2)+(4)$ is a pullback. Since $(1)$ is also a pullback, $(1)+(2)+(4)$ is also a pullback but this is just $(4)$ since the top and bottom composite in $(1)+(2)$ are identities. Now since $p$ is connected, $\Pi(pf)=\Pi(p)$ is an isomorphism, hence so is $\Pi(f)$. Since $(4)$ is a pullback, it follows that $f$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Perfect as always! Thank you.

Comment: Dear Arnaud D, in finding these proofs were you led by topological intuition, or were you "just" playing around with diagrams until the right one came to mind? On another note, do you know of any nice conditions under which weakly universal implies projective?

Comment: Mostly I just play with the diagrams :) I don't really have a topological intuition for this, in fact I'm studying this more from the algebraic perspective, to study the central extensions corresponding to an admissible subcategory as a generalization of the central extensions of groups.

Comment: I have just noticed I am unable to proof admissibility implies $\Pi_0$ preserves pullbacks along trivial coverings without at least assuming $H$ is full. Is this even true?

Comment: @Arrow It's certainly true when $H$ is fully faithful, which is the case I'm used to deal with. I have to admit I'm not 100% sure about a general adjunction.

Comment: I think I got it - even fullness of $H$ is not needed. The key is to consider the canonical comparison arrow $\text{canon}:H(\Pi_0B^\prime\times_{\Pi_0B}\Pi_0A)\to H\Pi_0B^\prime\times_{H\Pi_0B}H\Pi_0A$. Unless I am wrong, $\pi_{H\Pi_0B^\prime}\circ \text{canon}=H(\pi_{\Pi_0B^\prime})$, and since the latter is in the image of $H$ it has a local counit component. Moreover, this local counit component $\varepsilon_{\pi_{\Pi_0B^\prime}}:\Pi_0(B^\prime\times _BA)\to \Pi_0B^\prime\times_{\Pi_0B}\Pi_0A$ is precisely the canonical comparison arrow. What do you think?

Comment: @Arrow Your comparison arrow should be an iso since $H$ is a right adjoint. And I don't really see what you mean by local counit component?

Comment: The first comparison arrow is indeed an iso, I just didn't write that. By "local counit component" I mean the component at $\pi_{\Pi_0B^\prime}$ of the counit of the local adjunction $\Pi_{0/B^\prime}\dashv H_{/B^\prime}$. By admissibility this component is an isomorphism, and I think it coincides with the comparison arrow exhibiting the preservation of $B^\prime \times _B A$ be $\Pi_0$.

Comment: You might be right then :) I'm not 100% sure the comparison arrow will be the counit, but in any case it can be seen as an arrow over $\Pi_0 B'$, and taking its image by $H$ and pulling back along $\eta_{B'}$ will give an isomorphism. Since this is precisely what the fully faithful functor $H_{/B'}$ does, the comparison arrow is an iso. This is basically the proof given in proposition 2.4 of http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/1997/n6/n6.pdf, and apparently it works even if $H$ is not fully faithful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70636/discussion-between-arrow-and-arnaud-d).